# Facebook login on cordova app shows blank white screen

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk, html5-apps

This problem has been bugging me for a long time and I can't seem to find the solution, all the settings in my Facebook Developer panel are configured correctly, Site URL, App Domain and OAuth URLs.

When I run my app on my iPhone (I have it installed through iTunes) and click the authentication button I am successfully prompted with this screen:

[image]

However, after logging in, I am faced with a blank white screen instead of being redirected to my `main.html` page.

I am using the [OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) plugin along with Parse and the Facebook Graph API to authenticate and store my users data, here is my login code:

**login.html:**

```
$('.facebookLogin').click(function(){
  Parse.User.logOut(); // log current user out before logging in 
  login();
});

function login() {
  openFB.login(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 'connected') {

      console.log('Facebook login succeeded');

      Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", { // permission request to use email
        success: function(user) {
          if (!user.existed()) {
             FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                var firstName = response.first_name;
                var lastName = response.last_name;
                var email = response.email; 
                var user_id = response.id;

                user.set("firstName",firstName);
                user.set("lastName",lastName);
                user.set("email",email);
                user.save();
             }); 
             window.location.href= "main.html";
          } 
          else {
             window.location.href= "main.html";
          } 
        }, 
        error: function(user, error) {
          alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
     });  
    } 
    else {
      alert('Facebook login failed: ' + response.error);
    }
  }, {scope: 'email'}); 
}
```

**oauthcallback.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
   // redirects to main page
   window.location.href= "main.html";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I have added `main.html`, `login.html` and `oauthcallback.html` to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs list on my panel.

Comment: How are you running the app on the iPhone? Natively in iOS using React or in a browser?

Comment: It's running as an HTML5 App (through the add to home screen feature)

Comment: are you using cordova or just a web page. if you are using cordova you should try facebook plugin instead https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: or did you check https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

Comment: It is simply running as a web page (no Cordova).

Comment: has tried you print in the console the response "user" from facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your site is using SSL with a valid certificate.

There might be an error trying to redirect from a non-secure site to an encrypted site.